# C++ Child Class with a Child Member

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to remember my C++. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.  I have a parent class and a child class.  the parent has a member that's a reference of an instance of a different other object... the child class has a reference to a child version of that other object.

Basically, I want to have a Parent class that will denote what kind of members it will have, along with global member functions along with virtual ones that must be defined by child classes.

however, some of the child classes may need a specific kind of member object, which inherits the parents type.   here's an example.

we have a Person, which is inherited by BigPerson.
We have a Home, which is inherited by BigHome.

I want the Person class to denote that it has a Home, however, the BigPerson should have a BigHome (which is still a Home).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Home {
    public:

    virtual string sayHome()
    {
        cout << "Home";
    }
};

class BigHome : public Home
{
    public:
    int num = 5;
    virtual string sayHome() override
    {
        cout << "Big Home " << this->num;
    }

};


class Person
{
    public:

    Home& home;

    Person(Home& home) : home(home) {}

    virtual void sayHello()
    {
        cout << "hello";
    }

    virtual void talk()
    {
        this->sayHello();
        cout << ", I have a ";
        this->home.sayHome();
        cout << endl;
    }
};

class BigPerson : public Person
{
    public:

    BigPerson(BigHome& bigHome) : Person(bigHome) { }

    virtual void sayHello() override
    {
        cout << "big hello " << home.num;
    }
};




int main()
{
    Home home;
    BigHome bigHome;
    bigHome.num = 7;
    //*
    Person p(home);
    BigPerson bp(bigHome);
    //*
    p.talk();    
    bp.talk();
    //*/
    return 0;
}
```

The error i get is:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void BigPerson::sayHello()’:
main.cpp:65:44: error: ‘class Home’ has no member named ‘num’
         cout << "big hello " << this->home.num;
                                            ^
```

Comment: Note: `virtual string sayHome()` promises to return and `string`, but doesn't. This can have extremely unfortunate results at runtime.

Comment: ah yes. I wrote this example and missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

`class Person` has member `home` of type `class Home &`. At compile time binding it has no idea whether it refers to `Home` or `BigHome` object and thus it is not possible to point to members of `BigHome`.

One possible resolution is to use `dynamic cast` or an `assert` for type check and `static cast`.

```
BigHome *p = dynamic_cast<BigHome *>(&home);
assert(p != nullptr);
cout << "big hello " << p->num;
```